# Prevent grep returning an error when input doesn't match

Tags: bash, grep

I want to write in a bash script a piece of code that checks if a program is already running.
I have the following in order to search whether bar is running

```
 foo=`ps -ef | grep bar | grep -v grep`
```

The

```
 grep -v grep
```

part is to ensure that the "grep bar" is not taken into account in ps results

When bar isn't running, foo is correctly empty. But my problem lies in the fact tha the script has

```
 set -e
```

which is a flag to terminate the script if some command returns an error.
It turns out that when bar isn't running, "grep -v grep" doesn't match with anything and grep returns an error. I tried using -q or -s but to no avail.

Is there any solution to that? Thx

Comment: Note that `set -e` is not bash-specific, but rather applies to any POSIX-compatible shell (`sh` etc.)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Sure:

```
ps -ef | grep bar | { grep -v grep || true; }
```

Or even:

```
ps -ef | grep bar | grep -v grep | cat
```

Comment: The first is better in that it also works with "-o pipefail", another good fail-fast setting for bash similar to "-e".

Comment: This is working well if `grep` returns 1 for not having matches, but what happens if it returns 2 (e.g. error)?

Comment: As _André Fratelli_ stated, using `grep $options || true` ignores real errors! I've proposed a new answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49627999/307637

Comment: **Observation:** the approach using "`... | grep -v grep | cat`" will NOT prevent a script from failing if it has `set -o pipefail` in place, though it may suffice with `set -e`. The "`... | { grep -v grep || true; }`" approach will work with `set -o pipefail`, but for a cleaner solution that specifically tests for a lack of grep matches, see @myrdd's answer.

Comment: @Trutane, which answer did you mean? Please include the link next time since usernames can change/get deleted.

Answer (score 51):

#### Short answer

Write

```
ps -ef | grep bar | { grep -v grep || test $? = 1; }
```

if you are using **`set -e`**.

If you use bash's **`pipefail`** option (`set -o pipefail`), remember to apply the exception handling (`||test`) to every `grep` in the pipeline:

```
ps -ef | { grep bar || test $? = 1; } | { grep -v grep || test $? = 1; }
```

In **shell scripts** I suggest you to use the *”catch-1-grep“* (c1grep) utility function:

```
c1grep() { grep "$@" || test $? = 1; }
```

---

#### Explained

`grep`'s exit status is either 0, 1 or 2: [1]

- `0` means a line is selected
- `1` means no lines were selected
- `2` means an error occurred

`grep` can also return other codes if it's interrupted by a signal (e.g. `130` for SIGINT).

Since we only want to ignore exit status `1`, we use `test` to suppress that specific exit status.

- If `grep` returns `0`, `test` is not run.
- If `grep` returns `1`, `test` is run and returns `0`.
- If `grep` returns any other value, `test` is run and returns `1`.

In the last case, the script will exit immediately due to `set -e` or `set -o pipefail`. However, if you don't care about `grep` errors at all, you can of course write

```
ps -ef | grep bar | { grep -v grep || true; }
```

as suggested by [Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550484/prevent-grep-returning-an-error-when-input-doesnt-match#6550543).

---

#### [additional] usage in shell scripts

In shell scripts, if you are using `grep` a lot, I suggest you to define an utility function:

```
# "catch exit status 1" grep wrapper
c1grep() { grep "$@" || test $? = 1; }
```

This way your pipe will get short & simple again, without losing the features of `set -e` and `set -o pipefail`:

```
ps -ef | c1grep bar | c1grep -v grep
```

FYI:

- I called it `c1grep` to emphasize it's simply catching exit status `1`, nothing else.
- I could have called the function `grep` instead (`grep() { env grep "$@" ...; }`), but I prefer a less confusing and more explicit name, `c1grep`.

---

#### [additional] `ps` + `grep`

So if you want to know how to avoid `grep -v grep` or even the `| grep` part of `ps|grep` at all, take a look at some of the other answers; but this is somewhat off-topic imho.

---

[1] `grep` documentation ([POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html#tag_20_55_14), [GNU grep docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Exit-Status), [FreeBSD manpage](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep&sektion=1#EXIT_STATUS))

Answer (score 16):

A good trick to avoid `grep -v grep` is this:

```
ps -ef | grep '[b]ar'
```

That regular expression only matches the string "bar". However in the `ps` output, the string "bar" does not appear with the grep process.

---

In the days before I learned about `pgrep`, I wrote this function to automate the above command:

```
psg () { 
    local -a patterns=()
    (( $# == 0 )) && set -- $USER
    for arg do
        patterns+=("-e" "[${arg:0:1}]${arg:1}")
    done
    ps -ef | grep "${patterns[@]}"
}
```

Then,

```
psg foo bar
```

turns into

```
ps -ef | grep -e '[f]oo' -e '[b]ar'
```

Comment: Heh, I've done exactly this. It works because the expression *does* match **bar** but it *does not* match **b.ar**

Comment: @grok12, what shows up in the ps output will be `grep [b]ar` and the *regular expression* `[b]ar` cannot match the *string* `[b]ar` -- the regex will match exactly 3 chars while the string contains 5 chars

Answer (score 10):

Why ask `ps` to provide massive amounts of output with `-ef` if you only are going to throw away 99% of it? `ps` and especially the GNU version is a swiss army knife of handy functionality. Try this:

```
ps -C bar -o pid= 1>/dev/null
```

I specify `-o pid=` here just because, but in fact it's pointless since we throw away all of stdout anyway. It would be useful if you wanted to know the actual running PID, though.

`ps` automatically will return with a non-zero exist status if `-C` fails to match anything and with zero if it matches. So you could simply say this

```
ps -C bar 1>/dev/null && echo bar running || echo bar not running
```

Or

```
if ps -C bar 1>/dev/null ; then
    echo bar running
else
    echo bar not running
fi
```

Isn't that simpler? No need for grep, not twice or even once.

Comment: You are answering slightly different question here. The main one is about `grep` that can be used with any input, not only from `ps`.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo=`ps -ef | grep bar | grep -v grep` || true
```

Comment: x || true always true?

Comment: @user48956, read it as "x or true". Yes, that's always true: either x is true, or `true` is true.

Comment: Mind, backticks are bad form; better to use `foo=$(...)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make so:

> ps auxw | grep -v grep | cat

cat returns always 0 and ignores exit code of grep

Comment: It is not a good idea to ignore all exit codes since there can be other error except `not found` one. This solution will also fail in case of modes caused by either `set -e` or `set -o pipefail` commands.

Comment: Also, `| cat` makes your pipeline slower, because it's adding an extra process that needs to read and write all data. `|| :` or `|| true` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

All of it's pretty messy if you are using grep and it sometimes does not find any matches and you want to just continue. If you have ruby installed, you can do `ruby -ne 'print if /bar/'`, and it will just have no output if there are no matches.