# Check for substring using unix make

Tags: string, unix

Coding in [UNIX make](http://frank.mtsu.edu/~csdept/FacilitiesAndResources/make.htm), I have written:

```
cat $ sString | grep sSubstring > sResult
```

So I want to check if `sString` contains `sSubString` and, if it does, put the result in `sResult`.

Background: I have put the contents of a file in `sString` - if `sSubString` is present in the file, then `sResult` contains each line of the file containing `sSubString`.

This works fine when `sSubString` is in `sString`. When it is not, I get [Error Code 1](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).

How can I handle this correctly? The complete code is:

```
cat $ sString | grep sSubstring > sResult
if [ -s sResult -gt 0 ];then \
(echo "substring present" ) \
else (echo "substring not present" ) ;fi
```

*(With the error code, I never get to the* `else` *.)*

Comment: FWIW, I've tried other other [string contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash) solutions here, but those solutions do not work on this *make* file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might need this

```
cat $ sString | { grep sSubstring || true; } > sResult
```

[See this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550484/avoid-grep-returning-error-when-input-doesnt-match). The problem is that when `grep` doesn't find anything it returns a non-zero exit code. `make` will then think it is an error. So you just need to make sure that the command always returns a zero exit code by `or`-ing the exit code of `grep` with the exit code of `true`. The exit code of `true` is always 0.

Comment: Amazing! That was quick, and it works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

To check if a specific substring is present in a string, you can use the 'findstring' function.
More info here: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html.