# Git diff without comments

Tags: ruby, git

Let's say I added two lines to the file `hello.rb`.

```
# this is a comment
puts "hello world"
```

If I do `git diff`, it will show that I added two lines.

I don't want git to show any line which is a Ruby comment. I tried using `git diff -G <regular expression>`, but it didn't work for me. How do I do `git diff` so that it won't show any Ruby comments?

Comment: Probably not ideas, but for you could do `git diff | grep -v "^+\s*#"` depending on your use case.

Comment: There's nothing built-in to Git that will do this. It's somewhat complex, as comments are different in every language, and determining whether or not a line is really a comment or just looks like one is even more difficult without parsing files. This question has been asked on Stack Overflow a few different times, but I don't want to link to any of them because I don't see any satisfactory answers.

Comment: @JimStewart although tweaking http://stackoverflow.com/a/8291327/6309 would be a good start.

Comment: `git -G` matches regexp to show a whole commit, try a trick: `git diff | grep "^[ +-][^#]" | less`

Answer (score 5):

One possibility would be (ab)using git's [textconv filters](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Textconv) which are applied *before* the diff is created, so you can even transform binary formats to get a human-readable diff.

You can use any script that reads from a file and writes to stdout, such as this one which strips all lines starting with `#`:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep -v "^\s*#" "$1" || test $? = 1
```

(`test $? = 1` corrects the exit code of `grep`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49627999/4085967 for details.)

For C, there is a `sed` script to remove comments, which I will use in the following example. Download the script:

```
cd ~/install
wget http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/remccoms3.sed
chmod +x remccoms3.sed
```

Add it to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[diff "strip-comments"]
         textconv=~/install/remccoms3.sed
```

Add it to the repository's `.gitattributes` to enable it for certain filetypes:

```
*.cpp diff=strip-comments
*.c diff=strip-comments
*.h diff=strip-comments
```

The main downside is that this will be always enabled by default, you can disable it with `--no-textconv`.

Comment: Thanks. This is awesome! The only thing I had to tweak was the path to sed in that script.  It is at /usr/bin on macOS

Answer (score 3):

Git cares a lot about the data that you give to it, and tries really hard not to lose *any* information.  For Git, it doesn't make sense to treat some lines as if they haven't changed if they had.

I think that the only reasonable way to do this is to post-process Git output, as Dogbert had already shown in his comment.