# python script to call itself with xvfb

Tags: python, xvfb

I've written a script that generates a phylogentic tree with the [ete3 package](http://etetoolkit.org/), the script runs on a headless server thus it must be launched with [xvfb-run](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) (per [here](https://github.com/etetoolkit/ete/issues/101)).

I've setup the script to check (through a system call to `ps`) if it was called with xvfb.  In the case where the python script is launched without xvfb-run (e.g. `python script.py...`), is there a straightforward way for me to kill the process and re-run it correctly (e.g. `xvfb-run python script.py...`) from within the original script call?

I've tried hacking something together with `os.system()` calls to `ps`, but I'm not having much luck.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to put something together, just add the function `check_xvfb()` to the start of your script.

```
def check_xvfb():
    """
    Use of the ete3 library from the command line requires an X11 server
    which doesn't exist on this headless Ubuntu server.  One way around this
    is to use xvfb-run.  This function checks that the script was properly
    launched with xvfb-run; if not, it will relaunch it (with the same options)
    and then terminate the previously called script
                                                                                                                                           Parameters
    ----------                                                                                                                             none

    Returns
    -------
    none

    """

    # CHECK IF SCRIPT PROPERLY LAUNCHED
    # see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6550543/1153897 for explanation of 'cat'
    # grep -v ignores the ps -ef call since it'll match itself
    comm = 'ps -ef | grep xvfb-run | grep %s | grep -v grep | cat' %os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))[0]
    output = subprocess.check_output(comm, shell=True)

    if not len(output): # script not called properly
        print 'script not called properly, retrying...'
        comm_run = 'xvfb-run ' + ' '.join(sys.argv)
        os.system(comm_run) # properly call script
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print 'script called properly!'
```